# reverse tunnel on a multi hops ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, remote, ssh-tunneling

I'm a windows user, that needs to access his server at home using a double hop ssh tunnel.

I've configured via putty, a socks tunnel on a 2 hops ssh connection using a dynamic port, based on [this](http://www.matusbankovic.com/ssh-multi-hop-proxy) page:

there's a way to allow also on this configuration a reverse tunnel in order to connect the pc from the servers on VNC and/or RDP ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use local ports forwarding too, as described [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/things-to-do-with-ssh-ssh-tunneling.html).
But I'm afraid that you'll need a VPN service here to achieve that because of two hope SSH tunnel in your case.